# Comparing a double to Math.PI (converting double to String)

Tags: java, compare, pi

I'm trying to write a program that compares a double (entered by the user) to the constant Math.PI, after having converted both values to Strings and then comparing them char by char. I'm getting errors but I'm not able to see where I should change my code. Any tips/help is greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static int matches = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value to compare");
        double compare = scan.nextDouble();
        compare(compare);
    }

    public static int compare(double value){

        String input = String.valueOf(value);
        String original = String.valueOf(3.523);
                //String.valueOf(Math.PI);

        if(input.charAt(0) == 3){
            for(int i = 3; i <= input.length(); i++){
              if(input.charAt(i) == (original.charAt(i))){
                matches++;
              }
            }
            return matches;         
        } else
            return matches;
    }
}
```

Comment: **What** errors?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:11)
Sorry for not mentioning this!

Answer (score 0):

**Your question is not clear**

What is concretely the expected behavior here?

I can't manage to understand your thought process in the compare method.

If you wan't to compare a double with Math.PI, it is easy as double are  primitive variables, you can use the "==" operator, just do:

```
 if (scannedValue == Math.PI)
          System.out.println ("values are equals");
```

And for the runtime exception that you have it is because you did not pass a correct double variable to your scanner.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html